# Is it possible to get Homebrew to install from the latest commit on GitHub?

Tags: homebrew

I need to use the [LFTP program](http://lftp.tech) for a script I run. I tried installing it from the website using the instructions in the downloaded folder's "INSTALL" file, but running config always failed. So, I tried to have Homebrew install it, and that worked great.

I have no idea where Homebrew fetches its source from, but the latest version it pulled has a bug which the developer has since fixed on GitHub. Is there a way I can get Homebrew to install the source from the latest commit?

Comment: Here is the latest source for the Homebrew formula as of today: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/68d658a67d31b516807d38f2bf8c72cb7b213a65/Formula/lftp.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some packages, such as `numpy` have a `--HEAD` option.

```
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

but the `lftp` package doesn't have this option. One solution could be to implement it yourserlf:

```
brew edit lftp
```

**P.S.** the homebrew version of `lftp` already include a patch:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/macports/macports-ports/edf0ee1e2cf/devel/m4/files/secure_snprintf.patch
```

it's maybe the same you are looking for. You can see how it's apply whit `brew edit lftp`.